# Android Studio: I cannot find my Android Emulator as separate application anymore. How to fix this?

Tags: android, android-emulator

Since some recent versions of Android Studio, I cannot find the Android emulator anymore as one of Dock items / apps list.
I remember the emulator used to be a separate window/ application that can be opened/switched by clicking the item from the dock.

How to get that setting back ?

Answer (score 3):

Go to Android Studio => Preferences => Tools => Emulator and uncheck the "Launch in a tool window".

This will allow the Emulator to be launched as a separate application and will appear at the bottom of the screen on the Mac's Dock.

[image: emulator-on-the-dock-back-again]